# Что означает определение light-weight threads?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Корутины, согласно определению, это light-weight треды, которые "не используют много ресурсов, как обычные треды".
Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает определение light-weight треды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разных языках для это предоставляют разные средства, поэтому определения могут отличаться.

В целом, понятие *легковесных потоков* появилось в противовес обычным потокам или процессам операционных систем.

Обязательным условиям существования потоков является поддержка *вытесняющей многозадачности* на уровне процессора. Встретив одну из специальных инструкций, процессор может сохранить своё текущее состояние в памяти, и загрузить другое состояние. Подробности можете прочитать, например [здесь](https://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching) в разделе *Hardware Context Switching*.

Поскольку частью состояния являются регистры SS, CS ESP, EIP (RSP, RIP в 64-битных машинах), переключение контекста приводит к тому, что процессор начинает выполнять другие инструкции и работать с другим стеком.

Основная проблема с переключением в том, что оно занимает относительно много времени. Кроме того, каждый поток требует собственного стека — Рихтер писал, что в Windows для каждого потока выделяется 1Мб ОЗУ.

Наконец, чем больше потоков с разными приоритетами, тем дольше операционная система их переключает. Получается, что потоки, при том, что позволяют коду работать параллельно, просаживают производительность.

Выход заключается в том, чтобы в рамках физического потока выполнять несколько независимых небольших кусков кода. Реализуется этот механизм по разному.

Есть подход Go, когда две процедуры могут передавать управление друг другу. Такая возможность поддерживается на уровне языка и компилятора.

Есть асинхронное программирование, которое поддерживается на уровне операционной системы. В частности, в Windows потоки можно приостанавливать (усыплять) в особом состоянии, которое называется *alertable*, по-русски что-то вроде *тревожного сна*. В особую очередь потока можно помещать адреса функций, которые будут выполняться по очереди как раз в то время, когда поток *засыпает тревожным сном*.

Физически легковесные потоки всё-равно выполняются в каком-то потоке операционной системы. Они выполняются по очереди, друг за другом, не параллельно. При этом не происходит *переключения контекста*, поэтому накладных расходов почти никаких нет.

Важно, что этот код должен быть относительно маленьким и быстрым, и он не должен блокировать выполнение физических потоков. То есть они хорошо ложатся на некоторые сценарии, но не на все.

Comment: То есть, говоря light-weight имеется ввиду "легкость", появившаяся из-за отсутствия необходимости переключать контекст?

Comment: @Stvlpotapov, совершенно верно.